Why is Deuteronomy 32:51 in the plural?
Why is Deuteronomy 32:51 in the plural?:

מח  וַיְדַבֵּר יְהוָה אֶל-מֹשֶׁה, בְּעֶצֶם הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה לֵאמֹר.
48 And the LORD spoke unto Moses that selfsame day, saying:
מט  עֲלֵה אֶל-הַר הָעֲבָרִים הַזֶּה הַר-נְבוֹ, אֲשֶׁר בְּאֶרֶץ מוֹאָב, אֲשֶׁר, עַל-פְּנֵי יְרֵחוֹ; וּרְאֵה אֶת-אֶרֶץ כְּנַעַן, אֲשֶׁר אֲנִי נֹתֵן לִבְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל לַאֲחֻזָּה.
49 'Get thee up into this mountain of Abarim, unto mount Nebo, which is in the land of Moab, that is over against Jericho; and behold the land of Canaan, which I give unto the children of Israel for a possession;
נ  וּמֻת, בָּהָר אֲשֶׁר אַתָּה עֹלֶה שָׁמָּה, וְהֵאָסֵף, אֶל-עַמֶּיךָ:  כַּאֲשֶׁר-מֵת אַהֲרֹן אָחִיךָ, בְּהֹר הָהָר, וַיֵּאָסֶף, אֶל-עַמָּיו.
50 and die in the mount whither thou goest up, and be gathered unto thy people; as Aaron thy brother died in mount Hor, and was gathered unto his people.
נא  עַל אֲשֶׁר מְעַלְתֶּם בִּי, בְּתוֹךְ בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל, בְּמֵי-מְרִיבַת קָדֵשׁ, מִדְבַּר-צִן--עַל אֲשֶׁר לֹא-קִדַּשְׁתֶּם אוֹתִי, בְּתוֹךְ בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל.
51 Because ye trespassed against Me in the midst of the children of Israel at the waters of Meribath-kadesh, in the wilderness of Zin; because ye sanctified Me not in the midst of the children of Israel.
נב  כִּי מִנֶּגֶד, תִּרְאֶה אֶת-הָאָרֶץ; וְשָׁמָּה, לֹא תָבוֹא--אֶל-הָאָרֶץ, אֲשֶׁר-אֲנִי נֹתֵן לִבְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל.  {פ}
52 For thou shalt see the land afar off; but thou shalt not go thither into the land which I give the children of Israel.' {P}


It is a reference to Moshe and Aharon as it was originally stated in parshas Chukas, Bamidbar 20:12 also in plural:

וַיֹּ֣אמֶר יְהֹוָה֮ אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֣ה וְאֶֽל־אַהֲרֹן֒ יַ֚עַן לֹא־הֶאֱמַנְתֶּ֣ם בִּ֔י לְהַ֨קְדִּישֵׁ֔נִי לְעֵינֵ֖י בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל לָכֵ֗ן לֹ֤א תָבִ֙יאוּ֙ אֶת־הַקָּהָ֣ל הַזֶּ֔ה אֶל־הָאָ֖רֶץ אֲשֶׁר־נָתַ֥תִּי לָהֶֽם׃
But יהוה said to Moses and Aaron, “Because you did not trust (plural) Me enough to affirm My sanctity in the sight of the Israelite people, therefore you shall not lead this congregation into the land that I have given them.”

As a result of the incident, both Moshe and Aharon were denied to enter Eretz Israel. Perhaps, the name of Aharon, who passed away 7 months earlier, is hinted but not mentioned due to the maxim made of the 3 parsha names: Acharei Moth-Kedoshim-Emor (after death speak only holy things about the [good] person).

My mind went right away to Aaron, but wasn't he exonerated because of giving a good report about being able to take the Land?

@Ruminator Aharon was not involved in the story of the spies because he was from the tribe of Levi.

You are quite right. So Aaron too was denied access to the Land. Yikes. Well, please put that as an answer and I would happily mark it as the answer. Thanks.

@Ruminator what do you think about the ending that I added regarding why the name of Aharon is hinted but not mentioned?

That's helpful, yes. Thanks. We know Moses, the meekest man on earth, got triggered and smote the rock. So was Aaron's offense related to the golden calf?

@Ruminator I do not know. This was G-d's decision. Aharon was supposed to stop Moshe from hitting the rock. Maybe the combination of the two, was coming from the same source of being passive and created the verdict. I will try to write a question about it with other examples that I have, bli neder.
